# Why is mktime returning -1 for my std::tm

Tags: c++, datetime, c++11, time, mktime

I have a `std::tm` that looks correct.

[image]

However when normalizing with `mktime` I am seeing a `-1`

According to `man mktime`:

`The mktime() function returns the
     specified calendar time; if the calendar time cannot be represented, it returns -1;`

However, looking at the screenshot I posted, I dont see what is wrong with what is being put in the `std::tm` Is there a problem with `tm_gmtoff` and `tm_zone`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tm_year` member of a `struct tm` object denotes years since 1900, not the year number. Setting `tm_year` to 2014 refers to the year 3914, which is likely outside the range of `time_t`. On many systems, a `time_t` value is a signed 32-bit integer representing seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, which overflows in the year 2038.

The reasons for this are historical. When this interface was invented, years were stored using 2 digits, because that seemed to be the reasonable thing to do at the time. It was later updated to be able to refer to years after 1999 consistently, but it wasn't possible to change existing values without breaking existing code.

Something else to watch out for: the `tm_mon` member encodes January as 0 and December as 11; this is convenient for use as an index into an array of month names. The `tm_mon` value of 5 in your example refers to June, not May.

The `tm_gmtoff` and `tm_zone` members are non-standard; they're specific to your implementation. Implementations are permitted to add additional members to `struct tm`, but you should be aware only first 9 members in your list are standard; code that depends on any of the others will not be portable.

Comment: so if we store dates in: `2014:05:26:16:37:31:1:146` (%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S:%w:%j) that I need to subtract 1900 from the tm_year when creating the `std::tm` and add 1 to the `tm_month`?

Comment: _Actually_, the `5` in `tm_mon` corresponds to June, not April. Since it's 0-based, you need to _add_ 1, not subtract.

Comment: @keith - Thank you so much for the informative explanation. Problem solved.

Comment: This answer is correct, years need to be specified as the number of years since 1940. 

One additional piece of information that may help others is that the example in the original question would work fine under a 64-bit machine. I am working on a cross-platform application and recently got bit because it would work under a 64-bit Ubuntu but fail under a 32-bit Windows.